# how to send an email in c# on a button click after saving a file on the same button function

Tags: c#

in my application, i have a button which is used for downloading an excel file..

OnButtonClick code:

```
protected void btnmacdesc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fileName_macdesc.Length > 0)
    {
        fileName_macdesc.Remove(0, fileName_macdesc.Length);
    }        
    fileName_macdesc = "daily_macdesc_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyyyyhhmm") + ".xls"; 
    try
    {
        DataSet ds_macdesc = (DataSet)Session["sessionmachinedesc_ds"];
        gv.DataSource = ds_macdesc.Tables[0];
        gv.DataBind();                     

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName_macdesc));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                Table table = new Table();
                gv.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
                table.GridLines = gv.GridLines;
                if (gv.HeaderRow != null)
                {
                    PrepareGridViewForExport(gv.HeaderRow);
                    table.Rows.Add(gv.HeaderRow);
                    for (int k = 0; k < ds_macdesc.Tables[0].Columns.Count; k++)
                    {
                        table.Rows[0].Cells[k].BackColor = gv.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
                        table.Rows[0].Cells[k].ForeColor = gv.HeaderStyle.ForeColor;
                        table.Rows[0].Cells[k].Font.Bold = true;
                    }
                }
                foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
                {
                    PrepareGridViewForExport(row);
                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                }
                if (gv.FooterRow != null)
                {
                    PrepareGridViewForExport(gv.FooterRow);
                    table.Rows.Add(gv.FooterRow);
                }
                bool altColor = false;
                for (int i = 1; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!altColor)
                    {
                        for (int kl = 0; kl < ds_macdesc.Tables[0].Columns.Count; kl++)
                        {
                            table.Rows[i].Cells[kl].BackColor = gv.RowStyle.BackColor;
                        }
                        altColor = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (int lk = 0; lk < ds_macdesc.Tables[0].Columns.Count; lk++)
                        {
                            table.Rows[i].Cells[lk].BackColor = gv.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                        }
                        altColor = false;
                    }
                }

                table.RenderControl(htw);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());                      
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
              //  send_mail_daily(fileName_macdesc); 

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CreateLogFiles Err = new CreateLogFiles();
        Err.ErrorLog(Server.MapPath("../Logs/ErrorLog"), ex.Message, "Admin_admin_dailyreport==>btnmacdesc_Click");
    }
}
```

I am able to download the excel file without any issue. Now they are asking me to send that downloaded file as an attachment in the email on the same button click. Is it possible to do so?

So I tried to call a function ( send_mail_daily) at the last line of the button event, but I'm unable to attach it. The "save as" dialog box option is displaying after the execution of the last line. Please guide me to solve this issue or is there any other alternate solution.

function code:

```
public void send_mail_daily(string filename)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.To = "abc@in.bIZ";
    mail.From = "abc@in.BIZ";
    mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
    mail.Body = "this is my test email body.";
    MailAttachment attachment = new MailAttachment(Server.MapPath(filename.ToString())); //create the attachment
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);   //add the attachment
    SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "abc.in.def.LOCAL";  //your real server goes here
    SmtpMail.Send(mail);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the send_mail_daily before you CompleteRequest.

There is no reason that you cannot do this, as long as you get the code in the right place.

Comment: @schreidingers:  The "save as" dialog box option is displaying after the execution of the last line. if i specify the file path before itself its showing path error